# URL Rewrite in C# .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, url-rewriting, url-routing

Following is my code on globle.asax.cs file:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routeCollection)
    {            
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Account", "home", "~/Default.aspx");
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("logout", "account", "~/Account.aspx");
        routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Doccat", "dcat/{Id}", "~/Documents.aspx");
    }
```

This works fine for the first two routes and gives following URLs: 
http://localhost.com/home
http://localhost.com/about

And the last one gives following URL with my custom category ID: 
http://localhost.com/dcat/1

So far its fine, but when I have "http://localhost.com/dcat/1" this URL, it takes /dcat as a folder and all the links go inside that directory for the website. For example
http://localhost.com/home changes to http://localhost.com/dcat/home
and this affects all the paths in the site for images, css and all.

Please any one help me on this, this is too problematic now.

Comment: Can you show the code for one of the links?

Comment: Thanks for your question @ChrisGessler, there no code on my Default.aspx and Account.aspx page and only one line on the Documents.aspx page as follows: 
string id = Page.RouteData.Values["Id"].ToString();